# Display a record although the condition return zero record

Tags: mysql, sql

I have MySql query like this:

```
SELECT name, id_number, hr.id, file, created_at, updated_at 
From users u
LEFT JOIN homework_targets ht on u.class_id = ht.class_id
LEFT JOIN homework_replies hr on u.id = hr.user_id
WHERE u.role = 'student' AND hr.homework_id = 8
```

This query work just fine, but not like what I expected. I want to display all the student (users) record is displayed although they don't have a record on homework_replies that match the homework_targets is it possible? if it possible how can I accomplish it? thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move the `hr.homework_id` condition from `WHERE` to `ON` to get true `LEFT JOIN` result:

```
SELECT name, id_number, hr.id, file, created_at, updated_at 
From users u
LEFT JOIN homework_targets ht on u.class_id = ht.class_id
LEFT JOIN homework_replies hr on u.id = hr.user_id AND hr.homework_id = 8   
WHERE u.role = 'student'
```

(If you have it in the `WHERE` clause, you'll get regular `INNER JOIN` result.)